# Send Money from Merchant's account to specified paypal email address programatically

Tags: paypal, customer-account, merchant

I want to develop a feature like, transfer amount from merchant’s account to customer’s account.

Please refer below explanation.

Merchant set up PayPal settings on his store.

Now customer have to enter an email address to withdraw amount from client’s account. For this he have to enter an email address on specific page of site. After that when he click on “Withdraw amount” button, amount will be withdraw from merchant’s account to specified email address. This email address is associated with customer's PayPal account.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution for this."PayPal Masspay",using this method my above requirement is satisfied.